# What is the best/most intuitive way for a class to store a reference to a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a class that manages a vector of `unique_ptr`s:

```
class Foo
{
public:
...
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>> vec_;
};
```

I have another class, `Bar`, that I want to store some reference type that refers to an object in the vector. What is the most logical and intuitive way to achieve this?

The ones I can think of are four options:

### `Bar` stores a reference

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar(std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>& ref) : ref_(ref) {}
    std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>& ref_;
};
```

This is simple enough, but references can't be reset without constructing the object again. Is this still the preferred method?

### Use `shared_ptr`s both in `Foo` and `Bar`

```
class Foo
{
public:
...
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>> vec_;
};

struct Bar
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> ref_;
};
```

The problem with this one is that it implies that `Foo` and `Bar` have equal ownership over the object, even though `Foo` should have ownership. But maybe that isn't such a big deal? The reason I hesitate is that I've read that you should only use `shared_ptr` if the ownership really is equal. I also know that `shared_ptr` comes with quite some overhead compared to `unique_ptr`.

### Use a `weak_ptr` to show that `Bar` does not have ownership of the object (however, forcing you to still use a `shared_ptr` in `Foo`)

```
struct Bar
{
    std::weak_ptr<SomeClass> ref_;
};
```

This one seems like a nice and clean method to me. The only flaw I can see is that we have to use a `shared_ptr` in `Foo` even though `Foo` has sole ownership.

### Use `unique_ptr::get` to get a raw pointer that `Bar` stores

```
struct Bar
{
    SomeClass* ref_;
}
```

This is my least favorite option. The whole reason we use smart pointers is to avoid having to work with raw pointers. It feels silly to use them for something as simple as referencing a smart pointer.

Which of these options is preferred when factoring in performance and code maintainability, or is it subjective?

Comment: I would use `std::shared_ptr`, either throughout or in conjunction with `std::weak_ptr`.  Storing a reference to a `std:unique_ptr` has the danger that the original might go away and leave the reference dangling, and that's the very problem that `std:shared_ptr` was designed to avoid.

Comment: `even though Foo has sole ownership.` If you can _guarantee_ that in any possible case the object will be valid, just store references to the class. `we use smart pointers is to avoid having to work with raw pointers` No, we use smart pointers so that they cleanup by themselves automatically. They are still pointers.

Comment: If `Bar` is not going to participate in ownership, I would use a `SomeClass &`, or a `SomeClass *` if you want `Bar` to be assignable.

Comment: My suggestion is that, as a rule, whenever you think you need a reference type data member you should use a pointer type data member instead. Reference data members come with a lot of baggage and are basically never worth it in my opinion. This is an opinion on reference type **data members** not on references in general.

Comment: If `Foo` really did have exclusive ownership, you wouldn't need a reference in another class. I think you have kind-of exclusive ownership with shared access, but that translates to temporarily shared ownership, which best translates to `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr`. That said, you haven't considered two additional variants: Storing an iterator to the vector or storing a reference (or perhaps a `shared_ptr`) to a `Foo` object.

Comment: If using shared_ptr when you don't need is unpleasant to you, you might implement your own pair of smart pointer types which work like shared_ptr/weak_ptr but the owning pointer type is actually unique, not shared. However this saves you a machine word of space at best (you still will need a control block and a weak count, you save the shared count). If memory is really at such a premium in your environment, this might all be worthwhile, but if you have one word per such object to spare, I would recommend just using shared_ptr and not thinking too much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The whole reason we use smart pointers is to avoid having to work with raw pointers

No: the whole reason we use smart pointers is to avoid having to work with **owning** raw pointers.

See, for reference, the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-ptr):

> ### R.3: A raw pointer (a T*) is non-owning

We do indeed prefer smart pointers to own resources. However, this doesn't own the resource, so using a raw pointer is fine.

Your alternatives from worst to best:

1. Bar stores a reference: if you ever want to reseat it, don't use a reference. You say you *do* want to reseat it, so this is out. There's no benefit in trying to work around this, it just makes your code more surprising and no better.
2. Use `shared_ptr` in both places: do this if you need the object kept alive so long as a reference to it exists.

   Don't worry about "equal ownership", worry about whether the semantics make sense for your program. Your job is to decide whether resetting the pointer in `Foo::vec_` should destroy the object, not to express the communist manifesto in C++.
3. Use `shared_ptr` plus `weak_ptr`: if you want `Bar` to detect that the object has been destroyed.

   The advantage is that it documents the relationship nicely, and you don't have to worry about accidentally accessing a dangling pointer in between updating `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Having a non owning raw pointer is perfectly fine, as long as you are confident that you are not going to accidentally dereference once it is no longer valid.
With that being said, overheads are of a `shared_ptr` come mostly during constructor and destructor calls (+some small overhead in used memory as an extra control block needs to be allocated somewhere per object owned via `shared_ptr`), so as long as you don't care about every single byte of memory and don't pass around `shared_ptr`s by value everywhere you are not very likely to notice any significant performance difference- hence having a `shared_ptr` that owns the object and a `weak_ptr` used to store a reference might be a safer and a nicer approach.